# How do you correctly bind data to a sqlite query in Python/Pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, sqlite

I am writing a function within a class that allows a user to pass the name of a sqlite table to be read, the column names the user wishes to read to memory and discriminators that can be used to filter by keywords in specific columns.  The first part of the function builds the text string and places `?` symbols in the area where data is to be fed in via the `params` command.  I have a print command in the function to help me ensure the text string is correct.  The text string with the correct keywords works when manually entered into the sqlite3 command prompt, but is not working when implemented in my function.  I am guessing that my problem is with how I am binding the data to the `?` positions, but I am not sure.  My class and test of the class looks as follows.

```
class ReadSQLite:
    def __init__(self, database):
        self.database = database
        try:
            self.conn = sqlite3.connect(self.database)
            self.cur = self.conn.cursor()
        except sqlite3.Error:
            sys.exit('{}{}{}'.format('FATAL ERROR: ', self.database, ' does not exist'))
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------            
        def close_database_connection(self):
            self.conn.close()
            return
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
        def query_columns_by_keywords_to_dataframe(self, table, columns, column, keys):
            query = 'SELECT '
            for i in range(len(columns)):
                query = query + columns[i] + ', '
            query = query[:-2] + ' from ' + table + ' where '
            for i in range(len(column)):
                query = query + column[i] + " = (?)" + ' and '
            query = query[:-5]
            print(query)
            pd.read_sql_query(query, self.conn, params=((keys), ))
#=============================================================================================
#=============================================================================================
# MAIN PROGRAM
file_name = 'data/unittests/read_files/database_two.db'
test3 = ReadSQLite(file_name)
df = test3.query_columns_by_keywords_to_dataframe('test', 
                                                 ['category', 'food'],
                                                 ['category'],
                                                 ['fruit'])
test3.close_database_connection()
```

I am trying to use the code to read in a test database titled `database_two.db` which contains a table titled `test`.  The database has the following information in it

```
id            category       food
------------  -------------- ----------
1             fruit          banana
2             meat           steak
3             vegetable      celery
4             meat           pork chop 
5             fruit          orange 
6             vegetable      tomato
```

Answer (score 0):

While waiting for an answer I solved my own question and decided to post the response.  I found that I had made two small errors.  First of all the `?` should not have been surrounded by a paranthesis and second the binding `params` also should not have been surrounded by parenthesis.  The correct member-function should look like.

```
def query_columns_by_keywords_to_dataframe(self, table, columns, column, keys):
    query = 'SELECT '
    for i in range(len(columns)):
        query = query + columns[i] + ', '
    query = query[:-2] + ' from ' + table + ' where '
    for i in range(len(column)):
        query = query + column[i] + " = ?" + ' and '
    query = query[:-5]
    df = pd.read_sql_query(query, self.conn, params=keys)
    return df
```

In this case the function works perfectly.